# Proper way to convert NSString to NSDate on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsdate

I've been using this method to convert a regular NSString object to an NSDate, but tried submitting an update to Apple and it was denied. What's another way to do this in iOS?

```
NSString *date_str = @"2011-08-12T12:20:00Z";
NSDate *the_date = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:date_str locale:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]];
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use an [`NSDateFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Brief example follows:

```
...
NSString* dateString = "2011-08-12T12:20:00Z";
NSDateFormatter* fmt = [NSDateFormatter new];
[fmt setDateFormat:"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
NSDate* date = [fmt dateFromString:dateString];
[fmt release];
...
```

Note that as per [Unicode Technical Standard #35](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html), `NSDateFormatter` doesn't natively support single-letter time-zone identifiers (i.e. Z for zulu time).