# iPhone: How to convert "yyyyMMddThhmmss" format string to NSDate?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a string like "`20121124T103000`" and I want to convert this to `NSDate`.

I tried converting it with dateFormatter date format "`yyyyMMddThhmmss`" but it gives output as `2001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000` which is incorrect.

What is the way we can convert this string to `NSDate`?

Here is my code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddThhmmss"];
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormat dateFromString:@"20121124T103000"]);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper way to convert NSString to NSDate on iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892587/proper-way-to-convert-nsstring-to-nsdate-on-ios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like this,

```
NSString *dateStr = @"20121124T103000";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd'T'hhmmss"];
NSDate *d = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
NSString *st = [dateFormat stringFromDate:d];   
NSLog(@"%@",st);
```

Comment: Also consider setting the `locale` and `timeZone` as suggested in [Apple Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html).

Answer (score 4):

Your original code is quite close; instead of:

```
@"yyyyMMddThhmmss"
```

You should be using:

```
@"yyyyMMdd'T'hhmmss"
```

The only difference is the pair of single quotes around the 'T' in the string- you just need to let the app know that 'T' is a part of the formatting, not the actual date.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following Code.

```
NSString *dateStr = @"20121124T103000";
    NSDateFormatter *dtF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dtF setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd'T'hhmmss"];
    NSDate *d = [dtF dateFromString:dateStr];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd'T'hhmmss"];
    NSString *st = [dateFormat stringFromDate:d];   
NSLog(@"%@",st]);
```